# How to convert unstructured JSON to POJO using Moshi and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I came across one issue with some of the response we getting is not straight to parse and convert it to POJO. The format of response I am getting is as below

```
[
  "list",
  [
    {
      "@type": "com.exampe.model.ModelName",
      "number": 1,
      "name": "Test Name",
      "url": "/test/url/",
      "type": "f"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to ignore that "list" and parse a POJO in List of object ModelName. I am using Retrofit and Moshi Convertor but I am not sure how I can achieve this. Is there any way that I can intercept the response before it passed to Moshi Convertor or any different approach that I can go for.

Retrofit Snippet

```
private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .client(getHTTPClient())
            .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Retrofit` offers custom converters (see official documentation),`moshi` also should offer something similar.

I do not have experience in using `moshi`, but I have checked documentation and source code - it looks it is possible.

`Moshi` [offers custom adapters](https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master/moshi-adapters) which should do things you need. Take a look on [PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi-adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.kt), it has methods `fromJson()` and `toJson()` which allows you manually parse `json` elements in which way you like.

Even more. `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory` looks as an option you need for this.

> A JsonAdapter factory for objects that include type information in
> the JSON. When decoding JSON. Moshi uses this type information to
> determine which class to decode to. When encoding Moshi uses. the
> object’s class to determine what type information to include.

Comment: Thanks for the info actually PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory is not fitting with structure we have so I have decided to go with Custom Converter where I am intercepting the response.